# Playing Multiple mp3 files using android media player , at the same time . it jumps to the last mp3 on the list

Tags: java, android

I want to play 16 mp3 all together using android media player lib , these mp3 are saved locally in zip file . i am facing problem in android 5 and above .The problem is it only play's the last ,mp3 in the list , pausing and playing each mp3 after preparing is not a proper solution , i Need help .i have scratched my head for months now , its really ugly considering there is no error . length of the sounds is huge ,sound pool is not an option . below lolipop it seems to work fine . When debugged it seems to work fine , my guess is anroid art trying to screw with it , considering before 5 it use dalvik

```
public void musicstart(int id) {
            switch (id) {

            case R.id.rain:
                player.setVolume(value, value);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();

                break;

}}
```

this particular method i run it in loop which plays sound which are being selected , max can be 16 at once . i have already prepared them .

Comment: add the code in your Q to have alook

Comment: i have prepared each of them , and when i try to play more than couple it only plays the last one in list . but when i debug it works fine .

Comment: are you running each sound instance in a (new) thread??

Comment: i did try that , created thread class and ran MediaPlayer.Start() in to it but same result , by supplying sleeep to the thread it dose work but that aint a proper fix .

Comment: @Tasos consider i have initialized 15 media player instances , and i try to play them together at a stretch , in lolipop it just jumps to the last one ,but when i debug it works properly .

Comment: not sure, maybe if you want to mix 16 sounds at the same time you could try Soundpool -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: wanna play sounds together , but the thing is they are huge around 10 to 15 mb each 3 of them are around 25 mb with 44100 khz sampling rate , sound pool cant play . i just want to know why dose it skip . to the end and why it dose not play the rest only android 5 and above

Comment: I am facing the same problem , hope some one has the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by converting my `.mp3` files into `.ogg` and I am able to play multiple amount of `.ogg` file at a time .